# I need to execute Python script from C# UI

Tags: python, c#, user-interface

I have a python script that do deepfake stuff, and I need to execute that script into a UI program, I've tried to write it as a program, and have some issues

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace DeeepSliz
{
    public static class Program
   {
    
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static void Swagger()
    {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var script = @"C:\sliz\demo.py";
        var sourse = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);

        var argv = new List<string>();
        argv.Add("");
        argv.Add("--lol");

        engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
        ///
        var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;
        ///
        var errors = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);
        var result = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);
        ///
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        sourse.Execute(scope);
        ///
        string str(byte[] x) => Encoding.Default.GetString(x);

        Console.WriteLine("ERRORS:");
        Console.WriteLine(str(errors.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Results;");
        Console.WriteLine(str(result.ToArray()));
    }
   }
}
```

This is how it looks like, and i wrote a button to execute that code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    
    {
        Program.Swagger();
    }
```

and when i start the program, and click "button3" [this happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtjNZ.png), [and tihs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcR5L.png)

and ofc the python script (that works normaly)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import os, sys
import yaml 
import eel
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from tqdm import tqdm

import imageio
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import torch
from sync_batchnorm import DataParallelWithCallback

from modules.generator import OcclusionAwareGenerator
from modules.keypoint_detector import KPDetector
from animate import normalize_kp
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull


 '''eel.init('web')
eel.start('main.html', size=(700, 700))'''      


if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("You must use Python 3 or higher. Recommended version is Python 3.7")

def load_checkpoints(config_path, checkpoint_path, cpu=False):

    with open(config_path) as f:
        config = yaml.load(f)

generator = OcclusionAwareGenerator(**config['model_params']['generator_params'],
                                    **config['model_params']['common_params'])
if not cpu:
    generator.cuda()

kp_detector = KPDetector(**config['model_params']['kp_detector_params'],
                         **config['model_params']['common_params'])
if not cpu:
    kp_detector.cuda()

if cpu:
    checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
else:
    checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path)

generator.load_state_dict(checkpoint['generator'])
kp_detector.load_state_dict(checkpoint['kp_detector'])

if not cpu:
    generator = DataParallelWithCallback(generator)
    kp_detector = DataParallelWithCallback(kp_detector)

generator.eval()
kp_detector.eval()

return generator, kp_detector


def make_animation(source_image, driving_video, generator, kp_detector, relative=True, 
adapt_movement_scale=True, cpu=False):
with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = []
    source = torch.tensor(source_image[np.newaxis].astype(np.float32)).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
    if not cpu:
        source = source.cuda()
    driving = torch.tensor(np.array(driving_video)[np.newaxis].astype(np.float32)).permute(0, 
    4, 1, 2, 3)
    kp_source = kp_detector(source)
    kp_driving_initial = kp_detector(driving[:, :, 0])

    for frame_idx in tqdm(range(driving.shape[2])):
        driving_frame = driving[:, :, frame_idx]
        if not cpu:
            driving_frame = driving_frame.cuda()
        kp_driving = kp_detector(driving_frame)
        kp_norm = normalize_kp(kp_source=kp_source, kp_driving=kp_driving,
                               kp_driving_initial=kp_driving_initial, 
                               use_relative_movement=relative,
                               use_relative_jacobian=relative, 
                               adapt_movement_scale=adapt_movement_scale)
        out = generator(source, kp_source=kp_source, kp_driving=kp_norm)

        predictions.append(np.transpose(out['prediction'].data.cpu().numpy(), [0, 2, 3, 1]) 
        [0])
            return predictions

   def find_best_frame(source, driving, cpu=False):
    import face_alignment

    def normalize_kp(kp):
       kp = kp - kp.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
       area = ConvexHull(kp[:, :2]).volume
       area = np.sqrt(area)
       kp[:, :2] = kp[:, :2] / area
       return kp

fa = face_alignment.FaceAlignment(face_alignment.LandmarksType._2D, flip_input=True,
                                  device='cpu' if cpu else 'cuda')
kp_source = fa.get_landmarks(255 * source)[0]
kp_source = normalize_kp(kp_source)
norm  = float('inf')
frame_num = 0
for i, image in tqdm(enumerate(driving)):
    kp_driving = fa.get_landmarks(255 * image)[0]
    kp_driving = normalize_kp(kp_driving)
    new_norm = (np.abs(kp_source - kp_driving) ** 2).sum()
    if new_norm < norm:
        norm = new_norm
        frame_num = i
return frame_num

if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("--config", required=True, help="path to config")
   parser.add_argument("--checkpoint", default='vox-cpk.pth.tar', help="path to checkpoint to 
restore")

   parser.add_argument("--source_image", default='sup-mat/source.png', help="path to source 
image")
   parser.add_argument("--driving_video", default='sup-mat/source.png', help="path to driving 
video")
   parser.add_argument("--result_video", default='result.mp4', help="path to output")

   parser.add_argument("--relative", dest="relative", action="store_true", help="use relative 
or absolute keypoint coordinates")
   parser.add_argument("--adapt_scale", dest="adapt_scale", action="store_true", help="adapt 
movement scale based on convex hull of keypoints")

   parser.add_argument("--find_best_frame", dest="find_best_frame", action="store_true", 
                    help="Generate from the frame that is the most aligned with source. (Only 
for faces, requires face_alignment lib)")

   parser.add_argument("--best_frame", dest="best_frame", type=int, default=None,  
                    help="Set frame to start from.")

   parser.add_argument("--cpu", dest="cpu", action="store_true", help="cpu mode.")


   parser.set_defaults(relative=False)
   parser.set_defaults(adapt_scale=False)

opt = parser.parse_args()

source_image = imageio.imread(opt.source_image)
reader = imageio.get_reader(opt.driving_video)
fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']
driving_video = []
try:
    for im in reader:
        driving_video.append(im)
except RuntimeError:
    pass
reader.close()

source_image = resize(source_image, (256, 256))[..., :3]
driving_video = [resize(frame, (256, 256))[..., :3] for frame in driving_video]
generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path=opt.config, 
checkpoint_path=opt.checkpoint, cpu=opt.cpu)

if opt.find_best_frame or opt.best_frame is not None:
    i = opt.best_frame if opt.best_frame is not None else find_best_frame(source_image, 
    driving_video, cpu=opt.cpu)
    print ("Best frame: " + str(i))
    driving_forward = driving_video[i:]
    driving_backward = driving_video[:(i+1)][::-1]
    predictions_forward = make_animation(source_image, driving_forward, generator, 
    kp_detector, relative=opt.relative, adapt_movement_scale=opt.adapt_scale, cpu=opt.cpu)
    predictions_backward = make_animation(source_image, driving_backward, generator, 
    kp_detector, relative=opt.relative, adapt_movement_scale=opt.adapt_scale, cpu=opt.cpu)
    predictions = predictions_backward[::-1] + predictions_forward[1:]
else:
    predictions = make_animation(source_image, driving_video, generator, kp_detector, 
relative=opt.relative, adapt_movement_scale=opt.adapt_scale, cpu=opt.cpu)
imageio.mimsave(opt.result_video, [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in predictions], fps=fps)
```

idk how that fix, pls help.

Comment: A few things. One congrats on your first post! On future posts, please only post relevant code so the person that helps you does not have to scroll through 1000000 lines of code. And finally, dude you gotta comment your code to say what each thing does and use better more self documenting variable names

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat: I haven't done this myself, my answer is entirely from Googling.*

The error is saying that only one keyword argument is allowed.

This leads me to think that

```
OcclusionAwareGenerator(**config['model_params']['generator_params'], **config['model_params']['common_params'])
```

and

```
KPDetector(**config['model_params']['kp_detector_params'], **config['model_params']['common_params'])
```

are not valid in IronPython. You may need to merge the dictionaries and pass the combined one in with the `**` syntax.

Using the second case as the basis for example purposes, you can use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) package to create a new dictionary and then populate it with the values of the two existing ones:

```
import copy

params = copy.deepcopy(config['model_params']['kp_detector_params'])
params.update(config['model_params']['common_params'])
KPDetector(**params)
```

The deep copy is usually the safest, but `copy.copy` is an option as well and (based on a few assumptions) will likely not cause any issues.

Another, possibly simpler, option is to use [collections.ChainMap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to provide a combined view of the two dictionaries:

```
from collections import ChainMap

KPDetector(**ChainMap(config['model_params']['kp_detector_params'], config['model_params']['common_params']))
```

Comment: This is not mine python script, I tooked from Github, and I don't understand how merge the dictionaries and pass the combined one in with the ** syntax

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.